# "Yet before that", is it an idiom or anything else?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The paragraph lies below in italic, it's an excerpt from a novella by Stephen King.

*And he looked at her reproachfully. **It would be a little while yet before she picked up the book and threw it at him**, but that was what really tore it. That reproachful look. She could no longer stand it.*

I have trouble with understanding the bold sentence. I assume meaning would be something like "as soon as he glanced to her, she flung the book at him". But usage of three conjunctions (while, yet, before) in a row confused me. I think "while" in this sentence is used as main conjunction and "yet before" is a synonym for "just before", indicating that there is only a small interval between two incidents. Am I right, or did I just digress too much from actual meaning? Is "yet before" a legitimate use in English?

Comment: In contexts like this, the word ***yet*** is *optional* - it wouldn't really make any difference if it wasn't present, so arguably it doesn't "mean" anything there anyway. *I still have this job to finish, so it'll be a while [yet] before I can leave the office*. What exactly does ***yet*** mean there? I'd say something like ***from now*** or ***after now***. In your context, *It would be a little while **after that point in time** before [something else would happen]*.

Comment: Of course, there are plenty of *other* contexts where "yet before" could reasonably occur. Even as the first two words in a sentence: [*She pushes free of him, dresses, and prepares to leave. **Yet before** she closes the front door behind her, she sets Vinny's place at the breakfast table*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+leave+yet+before+she%22) (talking about Francis Ford Coppola's *The Rain People*, 1969). In *that* context, ***yet = but***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yet before* is not a phrase.

The sentence parses as *It would be [a little while yet] [before she ... threw it at him].*

*Yet* here is an adverb, in the sense "From this (or some stated or implied) time onwards, esp. for a specified length of time; henceforth (or thenceforth)" (Oxford English Dictionary, sense II.9.b)

Comment: Yeah, I saw my mistake. I mistook "while" as conjunction where it's used as noun. It seems more clear with that parsing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can see how it could be misleading - I hadn't thought of _while_ as a conjunction.